# Buffered Reader/Writer flushes files

Tags: java, file, flush, writer

I'm trying to create a method that replaces every line in my file with a given. Instead it just makes the file empty. Care to take a look and see what is up? Thanks.

```
try {

            FileReader fr = new FileReader(chooser.getSelectedFile());
            BufferedReader reader = new BufferedReader(fr);
            FileWriter fw = new FileWriter(chooser.getSelectedFile());
            BufferedWriter bw = new BufferedWriter(fw);
            String line = reader.readLine();
            Scanner scan = null;
            int i=0;
            while (line != null) {
                scan = new Scanner(line);
                ln = scan.toString() + add;
                bw.write(ln);
                bw.newLine();
                i++;
                System.out.println(i + " pass");
                line = reader.readLine();
            }
            reader.close();
            bw.close();
        } catch (FileNotFoundException e) {
            System.out.println("Can't find the file");
        } catch (IOException e) {
            System.out.println("Dude, it's impossibru to read.");
        }
```

The `i` in this method is too see how many passes the programme goes through a `while` loop, in this case 0, it doesn't initiate a while loop at all.

Comment: May not answer your exact question, but why not just count number of lines in the file and overwrite the file with new lines?

Comment: You are trying to `read` and `writ`e to same file. Instead create new file and write your replacing text.

Comment: noMAD, in the future it's going to evolve so I'm doing this the "hard way". Smit, that maybe a good point, but is there no way to do it in 1 file?

Comment: I’m fascinated by your use of the `Scanner`. It would be much simpler to let the `Scanner` read the source file itself instead of creating a new one each line, but anyway, what’s the sense of calling `toString()` on it? Why do you want to store [“information that may be useful for debugging”](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/Scanner.html#toString()) in an unspecified format in your file?

Comment: @VitalijKornijenko If you don't want the actual file then you can delete that file. And if you still want to stick to your idea of doing everything into one file then read all the content and store it somewhere, preferably into `ArrayList`, replace your content and write it to file.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want to overwrite the same file with your new lines you should do first all the reading, and then all the writing.

```
ArrayList<String> lines = new ArrayList<String>();

//start reader, go over each line

while (line != null) {
    String newLine = //make changes to line
    lines.add(newLine);
}

//close reader
//start writer
//write each line to file
```

Answer (score 1):

You opened file in replace mode, your `FileWriter` will empty file before first line will be written. Use  FileWriter(file,true) if you want to append.

Second problem is you are reading and writing at the same time. Try next sequence:

1. read whole file
2. replace all lines
3. write (replace old file)

Thus you will minimize problems count